# bash until not meeting condition

Tags: linux, bash

I have a shell script where I am running the following in bash:

```
GET_FIRST_SINK=$(pactl list short sinks | grep VirtualSystemSink | awk '{print $2}')

until [ $GET_FIRST_SINK == "VirtualSystemSink" ]; do
  echo "Attempting to re-try..."    
done
echo 'Done'
```

When I run this it just keeps looping.

The `GET_FIRST_SINK` needs to be a string with value of `VirtualSystemSink` for the loop to end.

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You don't actually retry anything. `GET_FIRST_SINK` is only set once.

Comment: That's the main issue. There are a few others. For one, you're quoting exactly the wrong thing; it should be `[ "$GET_FIRST_SINK" = VirtualSystemSink ]` -- you don't need to quote simple strings that can't be split on spaces or treated as globs, but you _do_ need to quote parameter expansions; and `=` is the only POSIX-defined string comparison operator.

Comment: I want to keep re-trying the loop until `GET_FIRST_SINK` returns "VirtualSystemSink" as the string

Comment: @jremi, yes, but you aren't retrying anything. Only when you run `GET_FIRST_SINK=$(pactl list short sinks | grep VirtualSystemSink | awk '{print $2}')` is `pactl` invoked and `GET_FIRST_SINK` updated, and you're only running that once. Expanding `$GET_FIRST_SINK` in the loop just retrieves the same value you stored in your variable back on the first line, it doesn't recalculate it.

Comment: Can you please give me an example to properly keep checking ...

Comment: Compare the [example in this guide](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_03.html) with what you are doing. In the example, take note of all the places `DISKFULL` is set.

Comment: BTW, there's never a reason to use `grep | awk`. Just make it `getFirstSink=$(pactl list short sinks | awk '/VirtualSystemSink/ {print $2}')` to have awk do both parts (all-caps variable names are used for special/reserved variable names meaningful to the system; you should avoid using them for your own names -- see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, keeping in mind that environment and shell variables share a single namespace, so conventions necessarily apply to both categories).

Comment: *looks askance at the TLDP link* (granted, I don't know about the beginners guide, but the "advanced" bash guide they also host is horrible and showcases a bunch of antipatterns in its examples).

Comment: @jremi, ...now, if what you wanted to do is make a *function* for checking the sink value, you can do that -- bash supports functions. That would look like `getFirstSink() { pactl list short sinks | awk '/VirtualSystemSink/ {print $2}'; }`, and then later checking whether `[ "$(getFirstSink)" = VirtualSystemSink ]`; that way, every time you call `getFirstSink` it gets a new value. But once you store that value in a variable, the variable continues to keep that value in it until it's updated, instead of recalculating every time it's expanded: Code goes in functions, values go in variables.

Comment: @charlesDuffy this is what i ended up with... 
function getFirstSink() {
    pactl list short sinks | awk '/VirtualSystemSink/ {print $2}';
}
until [ "$(getFirstSink)" = VirtualSystemSink ]; do
    echo "Attempting to load..."
    # do stuff
    sleep 5
done
echo -e "\n Complete all loaded."

Comment: Don't use the `function` keyword -- it breaks compatibility with baseline POSIX but gives you no advantage in return. And `echo` should generally be replaced with `printf` anywhere you would use `-e` or `-n`; see the excellent answer by Stephane on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo at our sister site [unix.se].

Comment: See also https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete re: `function` (note that it's present in multiple tables, discussing different aspects of its semantics and constraints).